# Trying to align bottom radio buttons with row above

Tags: html, radio-button

How do i align the radio buttons on the bottom of this page to match the row above?

```
 <tr runat="server" id="siteActiveRow">
        <td style="width: 30%">
            <label class="adminlabel">Site Enabled</label>
        </td>
        <td >            
            <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="rblYN" CssClass="center" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="yes" Text="Yes"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="no" Text="No"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </td>
        </tr>
```

[image]

Comment: Check whether the text inputs are wrapped in some other wrapping element, also this code is a bit too minimal , we need your entire form structure to narrow down some options

Answer (score 0):

took rid of the radio button and just changed it to one check box